# Remove post if found in $related_post

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, unset

The code below tries to remove any post found on `$related_post` but my approach is not working since `$content_post` is returned with those ones. I tried to fix but is not working and I can't see where I am messing up things. Take a look at the following code:

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position(&$posts, $return = false)
{
    $ad_posts = array();
    $content_posts = array();
    $related_post = array();

    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $position = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true));
        $post_date = $post->post_date;
        $post_modified = $post->post_modified;

        // each post with meta rw_adversiting_position 
        // will have a rw_advertising_related_link
        // let's add those to $related_post array
        if (intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_advertising_related_link', true)) != 0) {
            $related_post[] = intval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_advertising_related_link', true));
        }

        if (!empty($position)) {
            if (isset($ad_posts[$position])) {
                if ($post_date > $ad_posts[$position]->post_date || $post_modified > $ad_posts[$position]->post_modified) {
                    $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
                }
            } else {
                $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
            }
        } else {
            $content_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort($ad_posts);

    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach ($ad_posts as $position => $ad) {
        array_splice($content_posts, $position, 0, array($ad));
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($related_post);
    echo '</pre>';

    // if $post is on $related_post let's remove from $content_post
    foreach ($content_posts as $post) {
        if (in_array($post->ID, $related_post)) {
            echo 'YES   ' . $post->ID . EOL;
            unset($post);
        }
    }  

    return $content_posts;
}
```

This is the output when I run the code:

```
// var_export($related_post)
array (
  0 => 183002,
  1 => 182987,
  2 => 182923,
  3 => 182926,
  4 => 182704,
)

// echo 'YES   ' . $post->ID . EOL;
YES 183002
YES 182926
```

So there is at least two elements on the array, why them aren't deleted? what I am doing wrong? What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to remove from Array key.

```
// if $post is on $related_post let's remove from $content_post
foreach ($content_posts as $array_key=> $post) {
  if (in_array($post->ID, $related_post)) {
    echo 'YES   ' . $post->ID . EOL;

    unset($content_posts[$array_key]);
   // unset($post);
  }
}
```